# About autocorrelation function

Tags: time-series, correlation, autocorrelation

I am a little bit confused with the next example given in Brockwell and Davis,Time Series Theory and Methods, page 98.
[image]

In the example, is computed the autocorrelation, and at some point, the author says that $Corr(Z_2,X_1)=0$ I don´t have clear why, because If I see the expression $$X_t=0.9X_{t-1}+Z_t$$ clearly $X_t$ depends on $Z_t$. Moreover If I write in particular $Z_2=X_2-0.9X_1$ evidently $Z_2$ is depending on $X_1$, how the correlation can be 0 ??

Answer (score 1):

Note that you have written correlation at equal times ${\rm Corr}(Z_t,X_t)$, and the authors do not calculate this. They calculate ${\rm Corr}(Z_2, X_1)$, i.e. the correlation of the value of the random variable $Z$ at time $t=2$ with the value of the random variable $X$ at the previous moment in time $t=1$. These are independent by assumption, because this is how this stochastic process is generated: given the value of $X_t$ the random variable $X_{t+1}$ is generated using $Z_{t+1}$, which is assumed to have distribution independent of $X_t$.

What about $X_t$ and $Z_t$, i.e. values at equal times? As you have correctly noticed these are indeed dependent

$${\rm Corr}(Z_t,X_t) = {\rm Corr}(Z_t,0.9 X_{t-1} + Z_t) = {\rm Corr}(Z_t,Z_t)$$

In stochastic processes it is important to remember the time, at which you calculate something. It is like that at each moment in time $t$ you have a new random variable $X_t$ and even though it has the same name $X$ its properties are (related, but) different from those of $X_{t-1}$.